# Extend Mongo Default Config in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

I would like extend database mongo configuration about UuidRepresentation STANDARD. 
I want also use by default all possible 'spring.data.mongodb.*...' properties in *.yml files.
I did try this way:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongo() {

        MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = MongoClientOptions.builder();
        CodecRegistry codecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromCodecs(new UuidCodec(UuidRepresentation.STANDARD)),
                MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry());

        builder.codecRegistry(codecRegistry);
        MongoClientOptions options = builder.build();
        return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(), options);
    }
}
```

Uuid representation was changed successful but was created new MongoClient bean without implementation value from *.yml* file for example uri. I can use needed properties by mapping it to new MongoClient but when anyone will tray use other default properties from 'spring.data.mongodb.*...' must also remember map this value to new Bean.

It is possible to change default MongoClient configuration only about change UuidRepresentation without create new MongoClien Bean ?

I use SpringBoot 2.1.3 with java 8.